# Auto fill credit card billing name and address information for civicrm event registrant - webform-civicrm integration

Tags: civievent, civicontribute

Is it possible to auto fill the credit card fields when a person registers for an event using the webform-civicrm integration module?

Answer (score 1):

(Clarified that information needed was billing name and address information, not credit card details)

This information can be automatically filled in if the registrant is logged into the website (and has a valid Civi record attached to their website account), or by sending invitation emails with a checksum token inside.

Unfortunately I don't think there is a "same as above" checkbox on the event registration form.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself correctly. I want to fill in the billing name and address for the credit card using the event registrant. I don't want to fill in the credit card number or any credit card details. It seems to me that I should be able to check a box to copy the registrants name and address to the billing name and address so they don't have to fill in the same information twice. Sorry if there is an obvious solution.